# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/9/libquadmath.0.dylib

Tags: python, gcc

I am trying to solve a dynamic programming problem using GEKKO. The `gekko` object uses a `solve` method which references an executable `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gekko/bin/apm_mac`

This executable in turns wants to access a library `/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/9/libquadmath.0.dylib` and apparently it's not able to find the library, thus the error:

```
Error: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/9/libquadmath.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gekko/bin/apm_mac
Reason: image not found
```

When I go to the path: `/usr/local/opt/`, there is no `gcc` folder there which explains the error. But how should I fix this?

Comment: I am not sure if sharing the whole Python code for the Dynamic Programming problem I am solving is of any use (that's why I haven't shared it). But if it is, please let me know and I'll provide it. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you check [these](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/issues/71) solutions?

Comment: @Qiu I had not. Checking now. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Qiu I resolved the problem. Instead of running the problem locally, i.e. initializing the `GEKKO` object with `remote = False`, I set `remote = True`.